# Are ergonomic office stools aka "sitting stools" (i.e. seating without back and armrests) really better for your back?

Tags: back, sitting

Back problems are common in my family. Like the others, I do a lot of home office work at a computer.

Are ergonomic office stools - also known as sitting stools (seats without back and armrests) really better for the back?

When I do a web search, the answer to this question is yes. However, I don't really trust the sites because they all contain affiliate links to shopping sites.

Comment: "However, I don't really trust the sites because they all contain affiliate links to shopping sites." Very wise, and a good question. Try to find sites that are not for-profit, e.g. by using Google Scholar, and even there, look at disclaimers/disclosures/conflicts of interest. If you edit your question to use even one reputable source and a quote, you have a much, much better chance of getting a helpful answer. Besides, it's a requirement on this site. :)

Comment: A helpful site when looking for scientific answers as this site requires is [PubMed](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/), which indexes the vast majority of scientific publications in biology and medicine, a bonus is it has no ads because it is a .gov site!

Comment: If you've ever googled something, you just type in your search phrase and hit return. Instead of going to Google, type in Google Scholar, and search the same way you do in Google. Or, just click on @bob1's link to go to PubMed, and type in your search term. You'll get hits just like in any search engine.

Comment: there are not full papers, only ads for papers

Comment: @Sybil - there are full papers on Pubmed. Look for the ones marked "PubMed Central" or "PMC" in particular, these are free full-length papers that you can read on PubMed itself. Many journals also have some free content, but you have to visit their site to read it. These ones might have something along the lines of "read full content here" links, but won't necessarily tell you whether you need to pay for the content or not until you get to the article itself. Some journals also mark papers "open access" meaning they are free to read.

Answer (score 1):

Not really, unless you only sit for short periods of time.

During prolonged sitting, your posture will inevitably deteriorate, especially if you are focused on a task. In a sitting "stool", you have no back support by definition, which means your paravertebral muscles will have no chance to rest.

EDIT: there is little useful literature on this topic, especially because most of the studies i found were either assessing "novel chair designs" or were examining the acute effect on the posture.
This is one paper i found (of which i could only access the abstract) where they had the participant sit for 60 minutes in "ergonomic workstations" and found that

"Common ergonomic workstations were effective in eliminating some awkward postures. However, some important risk factors such as holding postures with an inappropriate lumbar spine curve (86% of the observations) and maintaining a posture for a long time (for 7-12 min) were observed in the participants' sitting behaviors"

Still, i don't know what the ergonomic workstation is without access to the full text, and i couldn't find more articles exploring the effects of prolonged sitting.

Comment: Welcome to Medical Sciences! We work differently than most SE sites in that we have a strict policy that all answers should be [backed up with reliable references](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-require-references-to-back-up-all-answers) so that the answer can be independently verified regardless of the reader's background. *See [this list of reliable sources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. If you still have trouble with this, feel free to visit the [help] or [meta]. Unreferenced claims can lead to answers being deleted.